# CI user defined Helpers and Libraries on production server are not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

On my production server (EC2) I'm trying since yesterday morning to till now to get my app worked. But no luck at all. Finally I learned how to handle some conf files and turned error reporting on which showed that one of my helper just stuck everytime I try to load =my default controller.

Also I have an authentication purpose Base Controller as CI's extending advise and there I have the class

```
      //in MY_Controller.php
      class MY_ProtectedController extends CI_Controller{
      //...............}
```

And two helpers in app/helpers: auth_helper,site_data_helper
And loading them to autoload just produce **DEAD WHITE BLANK PAGE** with **OK200 ! How painful!**

And of course the libraries wont be loaded. But why CI forgiving its own ? I have important libraries including Authentication, Permission, Imagelib Excel, Facebook. 
**FYI:All those are tested and qualified at localhost**

So Could anyone say why am I being so damned in this? Please Do help by saying anything!

**Also $route['xxx']='xxx/xxx.../x' is not following either**

And an example error log from tail -n K error_log run:

```
  [Thu Feb 20 02:17:41.179173 2014] [:error] [pid 9581] [client 180.234.43.53:36859]
   PHP     Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_profile() in
 /var/www/xxx/yyyy/zzzz/views/admin/templates/header.php on line 241
```

**Edit:**
I checked it call to parent::__construct() leads to initialize of Loader class but before that in Loaders construct it leads to two or more function or method references---- from there it leads to _ci_autoload() and it fails some where and exits without printing and logging anything. Why Cant it log in the logs file so that I could say where the heck has happened?

Comment: Can you check Helper by Helper and see if one isn't working? Usually one will brick the entire CI

Comment: I checked it putting an echo after a $this->load->helper('url'); It just get broken at that line and exit..so that leaving me a blank page every time with 200 OK

Comment: Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: Take the Helpers out one by one, comment them out in the code. Check your php error logs on your server

Comment: @Chitowns24 Well I've already done this! If look closely in my question u could see that I mentioned the helpers and libraries arent working at all. And worst the __construct() method isn't also get passed. Cause I believe (indeed) it's a helper function too. I'm scraed what gonna happen for libraries! I think CI will through a bomb toward me! (Not so funny I resent on this!!!)

Comment: check the apache error log ` tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log ` and find your errors and see what's wrong in the code

Comment: @Sundar Did it found the first helper() heck from there actually. That was my first clue for start debuging. Otherwise I would have been in dark for years!

Comment: untill seeing the error's you can't resolve. First find out if any errors are there are not in apache error.log file using tail command in terminal. And add log_message() and check your required function is working or not in applocation/log folder

Comment: @Sundar NO bro u dont get it I said I already did the ~ httpd> tail -n K error_log thing..in the morning. I have the clue from there that my helpers are not loading cause it says "your_helper()" is undefined..

Comment: update your error message in the issue may gives more clarity. if you are not loading manually check the autoload config file in application/config/autoload.php

Comment: @Sundar Edited .plz look for the error msg

Comment: compare your autoload file if locally working fine and all other files

Comment: @Sundar Yes they do..and they are doing this in local for months.. without any sniveling

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a case-sensitivity problem. Check the error log for misspelled calls (e.g. 'My_' instead of 'MY_' ) then also check the filenames.

Comment: try to change the log folder permissions

Comment: I've made it 755 and I'm the owner of the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your routing problem I advised to first check on your server that rewrite module is on if not please enable it from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

> And loading them to autoload just produce DEAD WHITE BLANK PAGE with OK200 ! How painful!

Have you enabled `error_reporting(-1);` and `display_errors = On` in your php.ini file?

Comment: I did that by last night Sir.. But wait, why error_reporting(-1) ?

Comment: `-1` means _enable all of the error reporting possible_.

Comment: Could u see the Edit in my question again. I've discovered that the routing ($routes[])is okay cause every url is being fired but all of them can't just pass the constructor function. I'm putting another question giving all descriptions.